# Proper way to make a reusable modal component

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, typescript, bootstrap-modal, ng-bootstrap

I've found a couple examples but they each seem to contradict or are designed for older versions of ng-bootstrap.

What is the proper way to create a simple modal that can be placed in a common folder and then reused for multiple modals on a page? I want to pass in a form component as the body of the modal.

And yes, I have seen the example on the official site.  But it does not take into consideration having multiple modals/modal triggers on a page.  It assumes you only have a single and don't have to target.  I need to pass in an id for a piece of data to be edited in the modal and saved back to the database.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation, I created a simple Modal and put it in the HTML file

```
<div id="InformUser" class="modal fade active" role="dialog" data-backdrop="static">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Status</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h5><i class="fa fa-info-circle fa-3x"></i><b>{{message}}</b></h5>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
 </div>
```

And use the same modal to dislpay different kind messages, set in the AngularJS Controller.

```
$scope.message = "My Message";
```

You can try something like this. In your case, you can use ng-show or ng-hide to show different Form components, based on some trigger id instead of using the Modal-Id.

Comment: Thanks but I am using Angular 6 and ng-bootstrap for Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 0):

you can make a reusable modal layout

**First thing to do is just add modal Layout**

```
<!-- The Default modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="modalLabel"></h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" style="font-size:19px;">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**then use a jquery to trigger the modal**

```
$(document).on('click', '.click-btn', function () {
    var dataURL = $(this).attr('data-href');
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('.modal-title').html(id);
    $('.modal-body').load(dataURL, function () {
        $('#myModal').modal({ show: true });
    });
});
```

Note: the **dataURL** is what the content of the modal you want to display

Hope it helps

Comment: down-vote because you should avoid use JQuery. Futhermore, Connie use ng-bootstrap -an "Angular library" that not use JQuery nor javascript of bootstrap- and to add a "click" to "document" it's innecesary use JQuery too

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling many hours with more or less same problem. I wanted to have hundreds of modal with different body and functionalities, but with some shared logic, header and footer.
The only way I see it is:
creating a modal component with defined header, footer and basic actions for buttons, modal-body where you put ng-content
i.e.:

```html
<header class="modal-header">
  <h5 class="modal-title">
    {{ title }}
  </h5>
  <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Zamknij okno" i18n-aria-label (click)="dismiss()"></button>
</header>

<div class="modal-body">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>

<footer class="modal-footer">
  <ng-template #readonly>
    <app-close-btn (clicked)="dismiss()"></app-close-btn>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-container *ngIf="!isReadonly; else readonly">
    <app-cancel-btn (clicked)="onDismiss ? onDismiss() : dismiss()"></app-cancel-btn>
    <app-save-btn [disabled]="isCloseDisabled" (clicked)="onClose ? onClose() : close()"></app-save-btn>
  </ng-container>
</footer>
```

```js
export class ModalComponent {
  @Input() activeModal?: NgbActiveModal;
  ...
}
```

then create component with body content use above modal

```js
export class YourModalBodyComponent extends ModalComponent {
constructor(readonly activeModal: NgbActiveModal) {
    super();
  }
}
```

```html
<app-modal [activeModal]="activeModal" [title]="'Wybieranie programu studiów'" i18n-title [onClose]="changeProgram">
  this is your modal body
</
```

and open it via NgbModal
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples#component

the other approach is to have Modal class with some shared logic and NgbActiveModal injected, creating ModalHeader nad ModalFooter components and using them in each of your modal.

any tutorial or demo I've found didn't allow for this kind of template and logic reusability.

Comment: I imagine you can open also a "template". Just your ng-template can be like `<ng-template #content let-modal> <app-modal [activeModal]="modal"`>your content here</app-modal></ng-template>` -and avoid this "strange" YourModalBodyComponent-

Comment: Thanks for your reply, and that's right for some scenarios, but that implies larger .html and .ts for your view containing modal (especially having multiple modals on one view), while what we want is having modals' contents in separate components, reuse it when we need to and use just one approach in our project.
I don't find anything strange about such YourModalBodyComponent. This one of ng-bootstrap's proposed approaches. The only difference is <app-modal> for shared header and footer. I didn't find anything like this in web, so I tought it might be useful for someone else. :)